# can't put jquery to phpbb forum

Tags: jquery, phpbb3

I has put some jquery script to overall_header template in phpbb forum but it not effect.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#vinanghi_caution").click(function(){
          $(this).hide();
       })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#vinanghi_caution").click(function(){
          $(this).hide();
       })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: in that case you should post some of your html aswell, we can see whats going on there ...